# Compare entire rows in two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have two sheets with same data and I want to compare entire row in two sheets.

```
On Sheet1 (old data)
Col A       | Col B
1001        | My Val 1
2001        | My Val 2
3001        | My Val 3

On Sheet2 (new data)
Col A       | Col B          | C
3001        | My Val 3       |True
1001        | My New Val 1   |False
2001        | My New Val 2   |False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to think in terms of comparing rows, make the problem simpler. It is easier to compare just a single cell - so first combine your "whole row" into a single cell. This is easy by concatenating all the cells using the `&` symbol.

Insert a new (hidden) column C on both sheets, that combines the other columns with a formula like:

- `= A1 & B1`

Now you have a summary that is easy to compare, because you are just looking at single cells and a single column.

---

On your new sheet, insert a new column D that uses `VLOOKUP` to see if the row exists on sheet 1:

- `=VLOOKUP( C1, Sheet1!C:C, 1, false)`

Now this will give you an error if the row is not found, and will return the row if it is found.

Your new column E (which corresponds to your old column C) can be calculated with:

- `=NOT( ISERR( D1 ))`

---

Hide unused columns as required.

Answer (score -1):

I started down the path of the accepted answer, concatenating columns.  But with 107 columns, this proved to be tedious.

My solution for this was to paste both sheets into one, keeping the columns aligned.
Then, on the Data tab, click *Remove Duplicates*.  If your remaining row count equals your starting row count, they're identical.  If they're not, you'll need to filter columns to find the ones that are not the same.

[image]

Comment: Just because you remove duplicates and have the same number of rows does not mean that all the data is the same between the 2 data sets. To do a compare between them in this way you could remove the duplicates, from each data set, then use the conditional formatting to see any unique values between the 2 data sets. I also don't see how the number of columns matters 2 or 2000 won't make any difference you can use a formula like =concatenate(A2:AA2) and that will concatenate all the columns from A to AA, or beyond. Then you can use the "Fill Series" to fill that formula through all of the rows .